# Google AdSense reloading?

Tags: google, google-adsense, cookie

Please tell me something about Google AdSense:

1) Can i reload ads by myself without full-page-reloading? For example refresh AdSense frame or call some script?

2) About "interest-based advertising" that works around cookies. Can i influence on it for setting my own interest-keywords? How works this mode?

Answer (score 2):

1) The easiest way would be to put them in a div and "refresh" that using AJAX. However, it's work reading through the AdSense T&Cs as this might not be allowed.

2) Not sure on this one.

Comment: I just liked to know that it is not allowed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Never do this otherwise your account will be blocked permanently and after that you can not even approach Google Adsense team to re-enable your Adsense account.

You will also lose all your ad generated money as well as Adsense which is more precious then anything as at the moment. There is no other program which can come even near to Google Adsense in terms of features and benefits.